# firestore where clause in firebase functions fails to execute

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a few documents from a collection that matches one of the field/attribute value as below

```
if(uid !== ''){
    try{
        const questions:any = []
        const appColRef = db.collection("sessions"); // best practice to use "ColRef" instead of just "Ref"
        const querySnapshot = await appColRef.get().where("uid", "==", uid)

        querySnapshot.forEach((doc:any) => {
            let data:any 
            data = doc.data()
            questions.push(data.message)
        });

        logger.log("all questions are:", questions)

    }catch(err){
        console.log("Failed to fetch sessions:", err)
    }
}
```

how i am getting error

> Failed to fetch sessions: TypeError: appColRef.get(...).where is not a function

I am using firebase functions gen 2 as below:

```
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
const { getFunctions} = require("firebase-admin/functions");
initializeApp();
const db = getFirestore
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#node.js_3

Comment: Note that this doesn't have anything to do with Cloud Functions, which is just a nodejs container that runs your javascript like any other nodejs installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do

```
const querySnapshot = await appColRef.where("uid", "==", uid).get();
```

`appColRef.where("uid", "==", uid)` defines a [`Query`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/latest/firestore/query) on which you can call the `get()` method.